# Correlated Proportions shown in a Mosaic Plot. What is the fitted model that generates residuals?

Tags: residuals, proportion, contingency-tables, log-linear

I have a 2-by-2 table of correlated proportions where I am plotting the positivity of two diagnostic methods applied on a sample of 216 individuals:

```
        Method B
Method A neg pos
     neg 100   2
     pos  23  91
```

Now I try to present this table using a mosaic plot:

[image]

To obtain the standardized residuals a log-linear model is fitted. This makes sense in two-by-two tables with several variables and counts, but does it still make sense in this type of table of correlated observations on the same subjects, where there really is only a "method variable" with levels c("Method A", "Method B"),and an "outcome variable" with levels c("pos", "neg")?

If so, what would be the equation for the regression model?

And what would be a way to calculate in **R**?

Thank you!